# How to know the folder path where is my laravel project in docker with WSL2

Tags: laravel, docker

excuse me for my English.

Long time ago, I installed a laravel project with docker in windows 10 with WSL2 using DEBIAN; now, I want to resume it, i.e I want to continue developing the project. My problem is that I do not know where is that project folder in Debian.
[image]

The above image show the docker image runnig.

I want to locale my project folder in debian, and continue developing the project, so ¿how Do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First click on CLI icon on your app docker container (fastfoot-api_laravel.test_1):

[image: cli]

And enter `pwd` command (this will most likely be the project directory, something like: /app, /var/www/app, etc.). Alternatively, you can try to `find / -name "composer.json"`.

[image]

Then open windows file exporer, click in address input and type `\\wsl$`.
After this navigate to your docker container (probably "debian*" name) and to the previously found folder structure (`/var/www/..` etc.)

[image: wsl in file manager]

Comment: Thank you friend. I'll try this and tell you how it went